# C/C++: lua_rawget() vs. __index

Tags: lua, lua-table

What am I not understanding? I want to return the original value in the __index function. See code below.

```
int getValue(lua_State *L)
{
  if ( !lua_istable(L, 1) )
    return 0; // return nil

  int typ = lua_type(L, 2);
  if (typ == LUA_TSTRING)
  {
    lua_pushstring( L, lua_tostring(L, 2) );
    lua_rawget(L, 1);

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Here I want to return the original table value..
    // BUT IT RETURNS NIL !?
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    return 1;
  }
  else if (typ == LUA_TNUMBER )
  {
    int param = lua_tonumber(L, 2);
    lua_rawgeti(L, 1, param);
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;  // return nothing
}

void test1()
{
  lua_createtable(L, 0, 0);
  lua_checkstack(L, 3);

  // add some entries
  lua_pushstring(L, "MyKey1");   // key
  lua_pushstring(L, "MyValue1");  // value
  lua_settable(L, -3);
  lua_pushstring(L, "MyKey2");   // key
  lua_pushstring(L, "MyValue2");  // value
  lua_settable(L, -3);

  // create the __index function
  lua_pushcfunction(L, getValue);
  lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");
  lua_setmetatable(L, -2);

  lua_setglobal( L, "TEST" );
}
```

The table shall not hold integer indexed entries.

The LUA statement for testing is:
"print( TEST.MyKey1 )"

Comment: Insert `lua_pushvalue(L,-1)` before `lua_setmetatable(L, -2)`

Comment: I don't get it. For what reason is this pushvalue() good for? If I add it, getValue() will not be called anymore..

Comment: Because just before `lua_setmetatable` there is only one value in Lua stack.

Comment: Ok. But what is the reason now, that getValue() is not called?

Comment: Answering myself: because the entry already exists..